# Convert c_int to default kind integer

Tags: type-conversion, fortran

I know that I can convert an default kind integer to an integer with kind c_int using `iso_c_binding` and `integer(c_int) :: i = int(1, kind = c_int)` (or `integer(c_int) :: i = 1_c_int`). Is there a way to this the other way round? I assume that `integer :: i = int(1_c_kind)` might work, but I can't find information if this is actually portable.

The documentation of the `int(A)` function, for my compiler (gfortran) reads "A Shall be of type INTEGER, REAL, or COMPLEX or a boz-literal-constant." I am, however, not sure if "of type INTEGER" implies "of type INTEGER of any kind", and if so, if this is true for all standard conforming compilers.

Yes, I know that in almost all cases c_int and the default kind integer is the same thing and `integer :: i = 2_c_int` will usually work, but in my understand this is not guaranteed.

Comment: First of all, what you are doing is "explicit initialization", which implies the `SAVE` attribute. This attribute should generally not be used, unless you really know what you are doing. And ommitting it, even if allowed by a flaw in the standard, is a bad practice that should be discouraged.

Comment: @PierU you're right and I'm aware of this. I just wrote it this way, so that I could illustrate the problem in an one-liner. I don't use explicit initialization or `save` in the actual code.

Comment: @francescalus yes, I read the documentation which, for my compiler (gfortran) reads "A Shall be of type INTEGER, REAL, or COMPLEX or a boz-literal-constant." I was not sure if "of type INTEGER" implies "of type INTEGER of any kind"

Comment: "of type integer" without further detail means "of any kind". In expressions and assignments in Fortran, there is most of time an automatic casting between kinds and types.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The behaviour of the `int` intrinsic function and intrinsic assignment are precisely defined by the Fortran standard. Any conversion required in explicit initialization follows the rules of intrinsic assignment.

`int(A)`, without a kind argument, returns a value of default kind.  `int(A, kind(0))` also returns a value of default kind (Fortran 2018, 16.9.100).

Intrinsic assignment for an integer left-hand side which differs in kind/type from the right-hand side is defined so that `i=A` is as `i=int(A, kind(i))` (F2018 10.2.1.3 p8).

This assumes that the conversion is allowed. There is no guarantee under Fortran 2018 that the kind conversion from the C-interoperable integer to default integer is allowed for all possible values of the C-interoperable integer entity. The `out_of_range` intrinsic function (F2018 16.9.146 - new in Fortran 2018 and not yet widely supported) can assist.

---

Since the introduction of type parameters (kind and length) to the language specification, if we give the name of an intrinsic type without further qualification we generally are inclusive: "integer" meaning an entity of integer type regardless of kind parameter.<sup>1</sup>

Yes, we still need kind parameters to match in many cases, such as for argument association in specific procedures, but wherever the Fortran language restricts the kind parameter of something that is explicitly noted. For example, stop codes must be 'integer of default kind', not 'integer', atoms must be integers of atomic kind, and so on.

---

<sup>1</sup> Before Fortran 90, "real" and "double precision" were different types. Now "double precision" is a real with a specific kind parameter.

Comment: Thanks, could you please share a link to the documentation of `out_of_range`? I'm having a hard time finding it myself

Comment: @M0M0 It is in the standard documents for F2018 linked in the [tag:fortran] tag page. It is not yet supported by gfortran https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/Fortran2018Status